# These Loops are Not Working Properly

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, foreach, while-loop

I have been working with the same loop for a couple days now, and it still won't work the way I want it to. I have tried both for, foreach and while and it still refuses to work.

The code that won't work is simply:

```
    if(!empty($_POST['submit'])){
        $d = count($_POST['deleteT']);
        for ($pi = 1; $pi <= $d; $pi++) {
        echo "Banned ".$_POST['deleteT'][$pi]."</br>";
        }
    }
```

If deleteT has two values: 'Bob' and 'Joe' it will print:

```
Banned Joe
Banned
```

Does anyone have any insight into why this is going on?

Comment: have you tried to start your index to 0 instead ? ;) you will also need to switch your <= to <. You could also put $pi-1 in your echo line and it will do the same thing

Comment: a foreach loop is much better in these cases, since the $_POST is an associative array, and not an indexed array..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start your loop index with `$pi = 0;` and only loop while `$pi < $d`.

Answer (score 1):

I think one of your problems is in your count statement, then with the `<=` condition in the for loop.

If you use `count()`, then just use `<`.  Example:

```
$c = count($my_array);
for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
 // do stuff
}
```

That said, an easier way to iterate over an array is with foreach.  Like this:

```
foreach ($my_array as $key => $val) {
// do stuff with $val or $key
}
```